# jQuery Как выбрать именно ту форму которая заполнена, если уникальный идентификатор форм input c значением?

Tags: jquery, form, input

На одной страницы сайта подставляются одинаковые формы. Где уникальный идентификатор `input` с полем `value="question"` `<input type="hidden" name="type_form" value="question">`
как мне выбрать данные именно той формы в которой заполнили данные .... пример форм

```
<form class="js-ajax-form form_grey">
                <input type="hidden" name="reachgoal" value="countryQuestion" class="js-reach-goal">
                <input type="hidden" name="type_form" value="question">
                <input class="field field_grey" placeholder="Имя" name="fio">
                <input class="field field_grey" placeholder="Телефон или e-mail" name="contact">
                <textarea class="field field_big field_grey" placeholder="Вопрос" name="question"></textarea>
                <div class="field__select-banner">
                        <div class="jq-selectbox jqselect js-offices js-custom changed" style="display: inline-block; position: relative; z-index: 100;"><select name="office" class="js-offices js-custom" style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 100%; height: 100%; opacity: 0;"><option value="0">Выберите ближайший офис</option><option value="485">Архангельск</option><option value="496">Белгород</option><option value="573">Владимир</option><option value="170">Воронеж</option><option value="266">Калининград</option><option value="272">Калуга</option><option value="267">Кемерово</option><option value="268">Киров</option><option value="394">Кострома</option><option value="409" data-offices="409||506" data-officesname="Ул. Тургенева 135/1, оф. 411||ул. Красных Партизан, 152">Краснодар</option><option value="172">Курск</option><option value="175">Нижневартовск</option><option value="504">Нижний Новгород</option><option value="466">Обнинск</option><option value="176">Пенза</option><option value="403">Пермь</option><option value="393">Подольск</option><option value="464">Пятигорск</option><option value="177">Ростов-на-Дону</option><option value="179">Саратов</option><option value="442">Симферополь</option><option value="308" data-offices="308||499" data-officesname="пр-т.Ленина, д.52/1||ул. Энергетиков, д. 20, оф. 103">Сургут</option><option value="180">Тула</option><option value="459">Тюмень</option><option value="182">Уфа</option><option value="183">Ухта</option><option value="404">Ханты-Мансийск</option><option value="491">Череповец</option><option value="271">Якутск</option></select><div class="jq-selectbox__select" style="position: relative"><div class="jq-selectbox__select-text">Калуга</div><div class="jq-selectbox__trigger"><div class="jq-selectbox__trigger-arrow"></div></div></div><div class="jq-selectbox__dropdown" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: auto; display: none; height: auto; bottom: auto;"><ul style="position: relative; list-style: none; overflow-y: auto; overflow-x: hidden; max-height: 135px;"><li class="">Выберите ближайший офис</li><li>Архангельск</li><li>Белгород</li><li>Владимир</li><li>Воронеж</li><li>Калининград</li><li class="sel selected">Калуга</li><li>Кемерово</li><li>Киров</li><li>Кострома</li><li data-offices="409||506" data-officesname="Ул. Тургенева 135/1, оф. 411||ул. Красных Партизан, 152">Краснодар</li><li>Курск</li><li>Нижневартовск</li><li>Нижний Новгород</li><li>Обнинск</li><li>Пенза</li><li>Пермь</li><li>Подольск</li><li>Пятигорск</li><li>Ростов-на-Дону</li><li>Саратов</li><li>Симферополь</li><li data-offices="308||499" data-officesname="пр-т.Ленина, д.52/1||ул. Энергетиков, д. 20, оф. 103">Сургут</li><li>Тула</li><li>Тюмень</li><li>Уфа</li><li>Ухта</li><li>Ханты-Мансийск</li><li>Череповец</li><li>Якутск</li></ul></div></div><input type="hidden" name="activeoffice" value="272" class="js-active-office"><div class="js-office-inner-wrap" style="display: none"><div class="select-office"><div class="jq-selectbox jqselect js-custom js-office-inner" style="display: inline-block; position: relative; z-index: 99;"><select name="offiinner" class="js-custom js-office-inner" style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 100%; height: 100%; opacity: 0;"></select><div class="jq-selectbox__select" style="position: relative"><div class="jq-selectbox__select-text"></div><div class="jq-selectbox__trigger"><div class="jq-selectbox__trigger-arrow"></div></div></div><div class="jq-selectbox__dropdown" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; display: none;"><ul style="position: relative; list-style: none; overflow: auto; overflow-x: hidden"></ul></div></div></div></div>              </div>
                <button onclick="buttonSendFormData();" class="button_small">Оставить заявку</button> <!-- Ivan Triumphov code Get8(amoCRM) добавил onclick="buttonSendFormData();" <p class="js-result result_text">Спасибо, ваша заявка успешно отправлена</p> -->
            </form>
```

как у меня сейчас выбираются данные из форм полное непотребство )))):

```
if($('.js-ajax-form').has('input[name="fio"]').length > 0) {
    var fioes = [];
    $('input[name="fio"]').each(function() {
        if (this.value != "") {
            fioes.push(this.value);
        }
    });
    var fio = fioes[0];
} else {
    var fio = null;
}


var office = $('select[name="office"]').find(":selected").attr('value');
var office_name =  $('select[name="office"]').find(":selected").html();
console.log(office,office_name);
```

Comment: выбрать данные из формы по нажатию кнопки?

Comment: да именно )))))

Comment: ну так на button метод on('click', function(){ $(this).parent('form').find... }) и погнал финдами извлекать значения своих полей.